# Lightweight CMS for simple website

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a very lightweight CMS that allows me to design my pages in the exact way I want. All those I found give you standard templates to work with that are quite limiting.

For example, I should be able to have generate a page with one full-screen image with a dynamic text area in its middle, or a toll image on the side with a few text areas scattered around. nothing too fancy... I just need freedom to place the objects wherever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest [Wolf CMS](http://www.wolfcms.org/) or [concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CMS for this, just make two files .php, one for the index, an another for setting *(, for select the texts or quotes that you need in the index.php. Of course, you maybe will need a database to reuse old texts.

Answer (score 0):

Perch lets you retrofit an existing layout with CMS content: http://grabaperch.com/features/existing-site and is quite lightweight. I've never actually used it myself, but the creators are well respected in the UK web design community.

Answer (score 0):

if you need an Asp.net application I'll suggest [AxCMS](http://axcms.net) which you can use custom template for each pages,but it not easy to use